# Unable to setup RKE2 slave node

Tags: linux, opensuse, kubernetes

I am trying to install RKE2 in MicroOS KVM and XEN Container Host from [openSUSE MicroOS - Get openSUSE](https://get.opensuse.org/microos/)

I am provisioning my VM with the followings combustion script that follows [Quick Start | RKE2](https://docs.rke2.io/install/quickstart)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cp vconsole.conf /etc/vconsole.conf && chmod 644 /etc/vconsole.conf
rm /etc/localtime && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
echo root:root | chpasswd

cp sshd_config /etc/ssh
mkdir -p /root/.ssh
echo <censored> >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo ssh-ed25519

# combustion: network
exec > >(exec tee -a /dev/tty0) 2>&1
echo test
#!/bin/bash

echo Schrift 1
zypper --non-interactive refresh
echo Schrift 2
zypper --non-interactive dup
echo Schrift 3
zypper --non-interactive install --no-recommends containerd conntrack-tools socat ethtool apparmor-parser

mkdir -p /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d
cat > /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/rke2-canal.conf << EOF
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:cali*;interface-name:flannel*
EOF

curl -sfL https://get.rke2.io | INSTALL_RKE2_TYPE="agent" sh -

systemctl enable containerd
systemctl enable rke2-agent.service

mkdir -p /etc/rancher/rke2/

cat > /etc/rancher/rke2/config.yaml << EOF
server: https://m0.k8b.intranet.domain:9345
token: <censored>
EOF
```

And I am getting this [error log](https://paste.opensuse.org/pastes/a27d3509438b)

And `systemctl status rke2-agent` gives the following

```
● rke2-agent.service - Rancher Kubernetes Engine v2 (agent)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/rke2-agent.service; bad; preset: disabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-02-23 16:58:33 UTC; 3s ago
       Docs: https://github.com/rancher/rke2#readme
    Process: 22816 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -xc ! /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 22818 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe br_netfilter (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 22820 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe overlay (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 22823 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rke2 agent (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
    Process: 22825 ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c systemd-cgls /system.slice/rke2-agent.service | grep -Eo '[0-9]+ (containerd|kubelet)' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r kill (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 22823 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 430ms
```

Comment: Your first error is `rke2-agent.service: Failed to locate executable /usr/local/bin/rke2: No such file or directory` so something went wrong with your install script.  If you are using MicroOS, I do not believe you are supposed to `zypper install` your packages.  AFAIU, you are supposed to use `transactional-update pkg install` as it is aware of the constraints of MicroOS like the read-only root file system.  I believe you also have to reboot after `transactional-update`.

Comment: @GracefulRestart The combustion script is already inside of a transactional update shell